# Angular 4 adding Footer to Mat data table

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<mat-table>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ytdBurnt">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="font-size: 65%" class="white-text" fxHide [fxShow.gt-md]="true"> Ytd Burnt </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="font-size: 65%"> <span> {{ element.ytdBurnt }}</span> </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- column based filter -->
    <ng-container *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
        <mat-header-row class="blue-back"></mat-header-row>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="25" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

I want to add a footer to the above mat table . I tried to add 
`<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total </td>` 
along with

```
<tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbpqmrjgvln?file=app%2Ftable-footer-row-example.html is `mat-footer-row` in action... can you share your stackblitz to show where you're stuck ?

Comment: @AkberIqbal I am not using tags which begin with mat word ie <mat-header-cell>.I dont have the stackblitz to share with you

Comment: can you share minimal stackblitz which replicates your issue?

Comment: @AkberIqbal okay let me check

Answer (score 1):

Add mat-footer-cell component in each cell

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="item">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="font-size: 65%" > Ytd Burnt </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="font-size: 65%"> <span> {{ element.item }}</span> 
    </mat-cell>
    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total </mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
```

and before closing mat-table add

```
 ...
 <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-footer-row>
</mat-table>
```